# How to make C++ pointers null

Tags: c++, pointers

While declaring all c++ pointer, all should by default be initilized to ZERO or NULL to avoid any random unwanted values. So that we can check if pointer is null that means not initilized.

thanks

Comment: This seems like a statement rather than a question.  What are you asking?

Comment: Umm..`int* p = NULL;` is that what you are asking?

Comment: Please submit your language-behavior-change requests to the [C++ Standard Committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++03, prefer `ptr = 0` over `ptr = NULL` (Bjarne S. says that. Read the excerpt below quoted from his [site](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Ebs/bs_faq2.html#null))

In C++0x, `ptr = nullptr` (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Null_pointer_constant))

---

[Bjarne Stroustrup says that](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Ebs/bs_faq2.html#null),

> **Should I use NULL or 0?**
>
> In C++, the definition of NULL is 0,
> so there is only an aesthetic
> difference. **I prefer to avoid macros,
> so I use 0.** Another problem with NULL
> is that people sometimes mistakenly
> believe that it is different from 0
> and/or not an integer. **In pre-standard
> code, NULL was/is sometimes defined to
> something unsuitable and therefore
> had/has to be avoided. That's less
> common these days.**
>
> If you have to name
> the null pointer, call it **nullptr**;
> that's what it's going to be called in
> **C++0x**. Then, "**nullptr**" will be a
> keyword.

Comment: +1 for also including C++0x in your answer.

Comment: I've never quite agreed with the advice to use literal 0 instead of `NULL` in C++03.  Writing `NULL` is semantically richer:  it makes it immediately clear that the value is a pointer rather than a mathematical quantity.  (The two are very different, despite both being represented by machine integers.)

Comment: @Wyzard: I think it's a matter of habit of seeing `NULL` everywhere. Once people get used to seeing `p=0`, it would appear to be as semantically richer, as you think `NULL` is!

Comment: it's just harder to `grep` or otherwise recognize with simple scripts... not that it really matters for simple scripts can't handle C++ rich syntax. @Wyzard: I think that some definition of the `NULL` macro were designed for C and could not be compiled by a C++ compiler because it has a stronger type system. Not sure though.

Answer (score 3):

```
void * ptr = NULL;
```

or

```
void * ptr = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make them `NULL` by assigning `NULL` or `0` to them.

C and C++ variables do not automatically initialize. If they did and you wanted to set them to a none-`NULL` value, the language would not be as efficient because they would be initialized twice.

Comment: Well that could be solved quite easily - if there no initialization, the compiler automatically makes one, (i.e. 0), just like the compiler automatically adds stuff like default/copy constructors, assignment operator etc., why shouldn't it be able to automatically initialize all pointers that the programmer doesn't?

Comment: @Mephane: What if you want it initialized later? I really don't consider this a problem to be solved. C and C++ are lower-level languages that give you more control over what happens "under the covers". Greater performance is achieved when the compiler automatically generates less code. I've used C and C++ for more years than I care to mention. This behavior has worked well for me. If you want a variable initialized, you initialize it.

Comment: What's the problem with automatic initialization to 0 and your late initialization actually being an assignment? It's not like you overwrite a useful value, but if initially 0 the pointer is at least in a defined state. I understand your point, but whenever I see C code with numerous pointer declarations at the beginning of a function, they're all manually initialized to NULL anyway. I've yet to come across a (well-written) piece of code where the author intentionally left a pointer unassigned for the sake of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it yourself:

```
Foo* pFoo = NULL;
```

Sounds like what you actually want is a *smart pointer*, which will catch these kinds of bugs for you.  There are [several to choose from](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of smart pointers such as (C++0x) `std::scoped_ptr<T>` and (Boost) `boost::shared_tr<T>`. If you don't use smart pointers, you get dumb behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two principles of C++ that conflicts with the proposal.

1) Don't add a new feature to the language, if it already has a fetaure you can use.

```
int* p;       // Problem here?  
int* q = 0;   // Fixed!
```

isn't big enough of a problem to change the language.

2) We don't want C code to be faster!

If

```
int*  vp[1000000];
```

where faster in C than in C++, the whole internet would be full of that "benchmark".

Comment: true but problem is freshers forget to do that and I have to spend nights to find it and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

No.  That's just wasted time if you are going to initialize them anyway and the flow of your code is such that you can be sure that they are initialized before they are used.

Comment: I've triaged many crashes from the field where pointers were not nulled out. One nasty crasher took days and days to solve. I could have strangled the idiot programmer... (Of course he was long gone though).

Comment: I'm not saying they should *never* be initialized.  Just not if they are going to be immanently setup before any other access is possible.   Perhaps I was using the word "if" incorrectly?

Comment: No, you used the word correctly. As long as it's clear the pointers gets initialized before use, it **would** be wasted time. I've been programming in some form of C for many, many years and this has worked fine for me.